# making a metric space for special open ball

Tags: real-analysis

is it possible to find a metric space for my arbitrary open ball?
for example I wanna find a metric
ℝ×ℝ→ℝ and my open balls be in the form of triangel or square(or any other shape)....

Answer (score 1):

Probably. How about [Taxicab geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry)?

Comment: @fatima. The above mentioned $l^1-norm$ and $sup-norm$ are the first metrics came to mind which happens to make squares (or diamonds) in two dimensional Euclidean Space. I don't know any metrics which have open balls as triangles (or any other regular polygons for that matter), though i'm surprised if i see a proof that it is not possible.

Comment: tnx.your answer was helpfull